# Delete specific line in a text file , using Sytem.IO

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I'm having a problem about, deleting a list of text, without deleting all the text that save on the file, if I search 1 the line with in the 1 will be remove and the other line will not be affected this is the example output..

Sample output:

Nike SB
8000
1

Lebron 7
9000
2

this is my code:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            string[] InventoryData = File.ReadAllLines("Inventory.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < InventoryData.Length; i++)
            {
                if (InventoryData[i] == txtSearch.Text)
                {
                        System.IO.File.Delete("Inventory.txt");            
                }

            }

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File or path not found or invalid.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you expect when you `System.IO.File.Delete("Inventory.txt");`. you have to write it all over again except that line

Comment: @AlgorithNewbie: Do you intend to do something like: _If a line contains the word that I am searching for, then delete that line_ ? Because, here, you are deleting the entire file, if the file contains the word that you are searching for.

Comment: Just a side note, you might want to use FileHelpers library for easy manipulation of tabular data instead of hacking the file yourself, or you might choose to have a random (binary) access file to modify the file on the go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to edit the contents of a text file inside disk. you have to overwrite the file again.

Also you can convert your array into list and use [`List(T).Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to remove first matched item from it.

```
string[] inventoryData = File.ReadAllLines("Inventory.txt");
List<string> inventoryDataList = inventoryData.ToList();

if (inventoryDataList.Remove(txtSearch.Text)) // rewrite file if one item was found and deleted.
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("Inventory.txt", inventoryDataList.ToArray());
}
```

If you want to remove all items in one search then use [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
if(inventoryDataList.RemoveAll(str => str == txtSearch.Text) > 0) // this will remove all matches.
```

**Edit:** for older .Net Framework versions (3.5 and lower) you have to call `ToArray()` because `WriteAllLines` only takes array for second argument.

Comment: `WriteAllLines` overwrites the content, so `Delete` is not necessary.

Comment: When I run it will error, the description is 
1. The best overload method  match for System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(string, string[]); has some invalid arguments.
2. Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Collection.Generic.list<string>'to'string[]'

Comment: try `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("Inventory.txt", inventoryDataList.ToArray());` @AlgorithNewbie

Comment: @AlgorithNewbie see the edit. do you still get error?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this simple with linq.

```
lines = File.ReadAllLines("Inventory.txt").Where(x => !x.Equals(txtSearch.Text));
File.WriteAllLines("Inventory.txt", lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong altogether, rather delete the line from collection and write that

```
List<string> InventoryData = File.ReadAllLines("Inventory.txt").ToList();            

for (int i = 0; i < InventoryData.Count; i++)
{
    if (InventoryData[i] == txtSearch.Text)
    {
        InventoryData.RemoveAt(i);
        break;            
    }
}

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("Inventory.txt", InventoryData.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: When I run it will error, the description is 
1. The best overload method  match for System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(string, string[]); has some invalid arguments.
2. Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Collection.Generic.list<string>'to'string[]'

Comment: @AlgorithNewbie, NO, it shouldn't be. Which framework version you are using?